# Alignment issue in mail message in Java

Tags: java, email, alignment

I am trying to get some chat messages from the system and creating the mail message body rom those messages. The issue i am facing is that both users have different name length due to which mail is looking cluttered:-

```
[2017-03-01] Amit : Hi
[2017-03-01] Rakesh Kumar : Hello
```

I want the messsage in the mail should be like this:-

```
[2017-03-01] Amit         : Hi
[2017-03-01] Rakesh Kumar : Hello
```

As of now i am trying to append the spaces according to max length of both of the names.but when string is sent in the mail(text/html) spaces are not preserved.

Can anybody suggest me a way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by creating a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using text/html as your email mime type, then you need to use Non Breaking Space (`&nbsp;`) HTML character instead of the space () character.

For example:

```
[2017-03-01] Amit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: Hi<br />
[2017-03-01] Rakesh Kumar&nbsp;: Hello
```

It should be something like the above. You will need to tweak the number of `&nbsp;` characters for adjusting the alignment. I think you get the idea.

The above snippet will get translated to HTML and get rendered in the email message like below:

```
[2017-03-01] Amit               : Hi
[2017-03-01] Rakesh Kumar       : Hello
```

So, you may want to do a replace in your mail content String like this:

```
mailContent.replaceAll(" " , "&nbsp");
```

See [this page](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/nbsp.htm) for more info.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used the same but some how still alignment is not proper.

Comment: Can you reformat the data into a table? With hidden borders?